# Scroll dialog after keyboard is on

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-keypad

I have some dialog with `EditText` fields. when i want to fill some `EditText` the keyboard is opened and I can't fill some fields above. i should close the keyboards and after click on `EditText` above. How can I make my dialog scrollable when the keyboard is on to avoid closing the keyboard?

Comment: add your `Layout` in `ScollView`.

Comment: I have done it but it does not help...

Comment: @G show me your layout then

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `windowSoftInputMode` to activity in manifest

```
<activity
...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

Comment: it does not help...
it is a dialog not an activity page

Answer (score 0):

xml (dialog_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:elevation="5dp">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

java:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    dialog.show();
```